# Is GPU-based binary classification using C# and LightGBM possible (yet?)

Tags: c#, machine-learning, lightgbm, ml.net

I am rather new to ML and started using ML.NET early this year. Perhaps I am not educated enough on it, but I am attempting to find information on implementing GPU-based binary classification using C# and LightGBM. Despite numerous searches I cannot find any documentation or examples. I would very much appreciate any assistance anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B., I am on the ML.NET team at Microsoft. We do not currently support GPU for LightGBM, but this is something we are considering implementing over the next few months. If you would like, please make an issue on our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/) and provide more detail about your use case.